# How to bind a ip address in Spring rmi settings?

Tags: java, spring, rmi

How to bind a ip address in spring rmi settings? Instead of listen all IP in Server.

Currently I am using:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="TestRmiService" />
    <property name="service" ref="testRmiServiceBean" />
    <property name="serviceInterface"
        value="org.test.TestRmiService" />
    <!-- defaults to 1099 -->
    <property name="registryPort" value="1099" />
    <!-- <property name="registryHost" value="127.0.0.1" /> this not working -->
</bean>
```

Comment: what does "this is not working" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but its not possbile to bind RMI just giving registryHost.
You have two alternative to bind your custom IP.

First one is write your own implementation of `RMIServerSocketFactory` or just pass `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname`=Your.Ip.Address as a parameter.

For the details just review the source code of RmiServiceExporter and the Java Bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4880793

Comment: Setting java.rmi.server.hostname doesn't affect the interface the listening socket is bound to. It only affects what is written into the stub.